# how do I assign a variable if 

Tags: javascript

How do I write "assign a variable if a action happens". I'm writing the following but it always returns 1. Thank you

```
function openwindow(){
testWindow = window.open("popup.php");
setTimeout(function() { testWindow.close(); },1000);
if(testWindow !== null){
    var t = 1;
    return t;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the "action" that should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(testWindow != null){
```

Sorry, wrong. What are you doing? Of course it always return 1. But what do you want to achieve?
`setTimeout` will be "set" and then instantly the next row of source code will be executed, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? You're testing the open function, browser everytime opens a window, so return "1" is OK, isn't it?

N.B.: Better way to write your condition is:

```
if (testWindow != null) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

or simpler:

```
return (testWindow != null) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want global variable `t` to be 1 while the window is open and 0 when it's closed after one second, here is better code:

```
var t = 0;
var testWindow = 0;
function openwindow() {
   t = 1;
   testWindow = window.open("popup.php");
   window.setTimeout(function() { testWindow.close(); t = 0; }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `testWindow` variable is an object and will not be `!= null` when the window is closed. You should use the `testWindow.closed` property instead. However, as @Tim and @Shadow Wizard pointed out, the timeout will fire after your code has executed.

Depending on what you want to do - you can check the window state as follows:

```
var testWindow;// declared here so we can access it from outside the function.

function openwindow() {
   testWindow = window.open("popup.php");
   window.setTimeout(function() { testWindow.close(); }, 1000);
}

if (!testWindow) {
    alert('testWindow hasnt been created by openwindow yet');
}

if (testWindow && !testWindow.closed) {
    alert('testWindow is open');
}

if (testWindow && testWindow.closed) {
    alert('testWindow is closed');
}
```

This will also work if the user closes the window before you do.

**UPDATED:**

Just to clarify - and forgive me if you get this already.

What setTimeout does is says:

*"execute this given function in a second, but meanwhile carry on executing the rest of this code"*.

So your function will finish executing as if that setTimeout didn't exist. Later on (after 1 second) the function in the setTimeout will fire.

Hope that's useful.